# jquery picklist where select option values are not numeric

Tags: jquery-plugins

The jquery picklist plugin only seems to work if the value of the options in the select are numeric e.g.

```
<select>
   <option value="1">Value 1</option>
   <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

as opposed to:

```
<select>
   <option value="one">Value 1</option>
   <option value="two">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

Is there an alternative or workaround to this that doesn't involve changing the objects populated in the list to have a numeric property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known bug that has been fixed. As of version 0.9.0, the [**jquery-picklist widget**](http://plugins.jquery.com/picklist/) supports non-numeric option values. [**Update to the latest version**](http://plugins.jquery.com/picklist/) for the fix.

See the [**Non-Numeric Values Test**](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-picklist/wiki/Demos) for a demonstration of non-numeric values.

Comment: I've updated my version of picklist and it does indeed work perfectly now for non-numerics. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that worked for you. :)  Don't hesitate to open a bug report on these kinds of things in the future... a lot of the time it's the only way they get fixed.